# If five numbered balls are taken at random, find probability that the second largest number is 8

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

An urn contains ten balls numbered $1$ through $10$. Five balls are drawn at random and without replacement. Find probability that the second largest number drawn will be $8$.

---

The root of my confusion lies in whether the balls are drawn one at a time, or scooped up at once.

Comment: the root of my confusion lies in whether the balls are drawn one at a time, or scooped up at once.

Comment: That doesn't matter at all.  It is still sampling without replacement.  How many balls have a value that are greater than 8?  Less than 8?

Comment: since second largest number is eight, there is one other ball with value nine or ten. Three other balls with values < 8.

Comment: Yes. So you have to count the number of ways that can happen and compare it with the total number of possibilities.

Comment: Right.  How many ways of choosing one ball out of the two larger?  How many ways of choosing three balls out of the seven smaller?  And how big is your sample space?

Comment: Got it!The second part of @David's answer is worked out like this. for two larger ball choices, there are C(7,3) ways of choosing smaller balls. And sample space is C(10,5): ways of blindly choosing 5 balls from 10 in urn. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addressing your comment as to whether the balls are drawn one at a time, or together: it doesn't matter.

If you draw the balls one at a time, you would probably think of choosing five numbers from ten, including the number $8$, with order being important.  To count the number of favourable draws,

- choose a place for the $8$. . . . . . $5$ ways
- choose a digit greater than $8$ (so that $8$ is the second largest). . . . . . $2$ ways
- choose a place for this digit. . . . . . $4$ ways
- choose three digits below $8$, with order important. . . . . . $7\times6\times5$ ways.

To count the total number of draws:

- choose five digits, order important. . . . . . $10\times9\times8\times7\times6$ ways.

The probability is
$$\frac{5\times2\times4\times7\times6\times5}{10\times9\times8\times7\times6}=\frac{5}{18}\ .$$

If you draw them all together you are probably thinking of order as being irrelevant.  The number of favourable draws is $2C(7,3)$, the total number of draws is $C(10,5)$, and the probability is
$$\frac{2C(7,3)}{C(10,5)}=\frac{2\times7\times6\times5}{3\times2\times1}\frac{5\times4\times3\times2\times1}{10\times9\times8\times7\times6}=\frac{5}{18}\ .$$